# In C, computing an equation using user input values is not giving the expected result?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, math

I am doing an assignment for my class but I am stuck. The assignment is to:

Write a recursive program to precompute Fibonacci numbers and store them in an array. Fibonacci formula is Fib(0) = 1, Fib(1) = 1 and Fib(i) = Fib(i − 1) + Fib(i − 2). Store the ith Fibonacci number at index i. Have a loop to read i and print i and ith Fibonacci number. Use −1 to quit the loop. My output is wrong but I don't know how to fix it. I have been trying for a while now but I just couldn't pinpoint my mistake.

My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>  
double Fib[50]; //globally declared 
int fib(int i)
{               
    for(i=0; i<50; i++) //loop to scan 
    {   
        scanf("%lf", &Fib[i]); //scan and store numbers in an array
        if (Fib[i]==-1) //i =-1 will end loop
            break;
    }       
    Fib[i]= Fib[i-1]+Fib[i-2];//formula     
    if(Fib[i]==0||Fib[i]==1) //i=0 and i=1 will print 1
        Fib[i]=1;
    else if(i>1) //performs the operation with the formula
        printf("%d  %lf\n", i, Fib[i]);
}   
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    fib(i); 
return 0;    
}
Expected result:
user input: 4 10 20 15 5 -1
output:
4 5.000000
10 89.000000
20 10946.000000
15 987.000000
5 8.000000  

My output:
5  20.000000
```

Comment: A few points about your code: Why do you pass `i` as an argument to the `fib` function, instead of defining it as a local variable inside the function? And after the loop the value of `i` can be equal to `50`, which is *out of bounds* of the array. Or the value of `i` could be less than `2` which means `i - 1` and `i - 2` could be out of bounds.

Comment: Regarding your problem, you might want to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Why do you expect multiple outputs from your code, considering that you only have a *single* (and conditional!) `printf` call? Your function really doesn't make much sense, and it most certainly won't calculate a Fibonacci sequence. My guess is that you should do some *recursion* (since that's used in the formula you show).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A couple points**:

- Your program isn't recursive
- Compute all of Fib first with your recursive function then after
  handle user input in a loop

**The code below has the structure for dealing with user input, do the recursion**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// It would make sense for this to store unsigned long long instead of double
// because Fibonacci numbers are always positive integers
unsigned long long Fib[50];

// Your assignment specifically said use a recursive program to compute Fib.
// This is not a recursive function, but it is correct, I will leave the
// recursion for you to work out
void populateFib() {
    Fib[0] = 1;
    Fib[1] = 1;
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 2; i < 50; ++i)
        Fib[i] = Fib[i - 1] + Fib[i - 2];
}

int main() {
    // First compute Fib
    populateFib();

    // Deal with user input in an infinite loop
    for (;;) {
        int input;
        scanf("%d", &input);

        // Condition for breaking the infinite loop
        if (input == -1)
            break;

        // Sanity check the user won't read out of bounds
        if (input < 0 || input >= 50) {
            printf("No!\n");
            continue;
        }

        // Display what the user wants
        printf("%d %llu\n", input, Fib[input]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```